# VB.NET How to get a control collection to cast to the enumerable in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

Pretty simple, I need to resize a few hundred pictureboxes inside a FlowLayoutPanel. In an effort to speed it up, I'm experimenting with Parallel.ForEach

I'm trying to turn this for each loop

```
For Each p As Control In Me.PanelMain.Controls
            p.Size = New Size(GWidth, GHeight)
Next
```

Into a Parallel.ForEach loop. I'm struggling with the syntax, and online documentation is particularly cryptic this time around. I've gotten this far:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Of Control)(Me.PanelMain.Controls, Sub(resize)
                                                    resize.Size = New Size(GWidth, GHeight)
                                                End Sub
                                    )
```

This gives an error on compile "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ControlCollection' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Windows.Forms.Control]'.'" And I really just don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ControlCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` is a type which `Parallel.ForEach` expecting.

To cast controls collection to IEnumerable(Of Control) you can use

```
Dim controls = Me.PanelMain.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()

Parallel.ForEach(controls, Sub(control) control.Size = New Size(GWidth, GHeight))
```

Note that UI controls can be updated only on the thread they has been created on. So splitting resizing between multiple threads will not work as you expect.

I would reconsider having hundreds of pictureboxes on the form, can user see all pictureboxes at once?

That said, you can try to speed up updating controls by suspending form redrawing after every control resize.

```
Me.PanelMain.SuspendLayout();

Dim newSize As New Size(GWidth, GHeight)
For Each p As Control In Me.PanelMain.Controls
    p.Size = newSize
Next

Me.PanelMain.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: The user can only see a collection of the pictures at once, but the user will want to scroll through them, so if they're not all visible they would have to be rapidly loaded and unloaded from the section that is in view. Is there a more efficient way to draw the images and using a bunch of pictureboxes that I should explore?

Comment: EDIT: Changed Me.SuspendLayout to PanelMain.SuspendLayout and that got me the speedup I needed. Thanks so much! Got me a 100x speed increase. Also gonna Dim newSize outside of the loop like you suggested.